# how to set width, heigh icon on toolbar on xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Main.axml

```html
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<!-- your content layout -->
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:titleTextColor="@android:color/background_light" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navmenu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

```html
<item
      android:id="@+id/menu_share"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_48dp"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:title="Search"
    
      />

 
</menu>
```

```html
  public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(Android.Views.IMenu menu)
  {
   MenuInflater.Inflate (Resource.Menu.Action_menu, menu);
   return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu (menu);
  }
```

I saw that icon's very big. if I set a icon smaller then it don't show clearly icon. So I want to set a big icon but it be set width and heigh smaller.

About width=20dp and heigh too.

Answer (score 1):

The standard icon size for Toolbar items on android is **24dp** as described in the [Material Icons Guide](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icons-for-android) and in the [Icons style guidelines from Google](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons) (see clearance section).

So make sure to scale your icon to that size outside of the app or find an icon which has the correct size. [Google's own Material Design Icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) are a good place to find such icons scaled to the sizes you need.

Alternatively, with Vector Drawables being supported in Android M and in the AppCompat libraries, then you could look into converting your icons into Vector images instead. This will save a lot of space in the app and make them nicely scalable.